# PackageInfo LoadLabel slow performance

Tags: java, android, performance

I am coding an app for Android, where getting a label (actual name) of the application is extremelly slow. Particularly this code is performing really badly:

```
packageInfo.loadLabel(pm);
```

Just to give you some metrics. On an Android device with 400 installed applications, it'll take less than a second to build a list of all application packagenames (com.android.*, etc..). However, it'll take over 30 seconds to get an actual name for each of the apps.

I've tried this code as well, but it's pretty much the same result (very slow):

```
(String)pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo);
```

**Question:** If application packagename is known (i.e. "com.android.htmlviewer"), is there an alternative way to grab an application name (i.e. "HTML Viewer") quickly?

Comment: Is there really no differenrce between loadLabel and getApplicationLabel ?

Comment: This remains an issue in Android 9+.   Localized labels are maintained as resources in each app. When the system locale is changed, any of those labels can change and so they have to be re-read. Evidently, the system maintains a cache of app labels, because it produces a sorted list of apps very quickly.  But it seems `loadLabel` re-fetches the label from resources, bypassing that cache.  Now... is there some way for other apps to access the system's cached list of app labels?

Answer (score 1):

You could build a database in your app of "known" application names, and update it every time your app comes across a new package.  The first run through will take a while, but after that you could save a lot of time by only checking one or two package names.