# Why my button reacts very slowly in Android?

Tags: android, button, launcher

I'm working on a launcher app, where I've created a homescreen and on my homescreen there is a app drawer button. When I press the app drawer button, it takes very long time to open up my apps activity! I don't know why this is happening, I tried on high end devices like Nexus 5, but no changes. Any solutions? Here's my code:

**From HomeScreen to Apps Activity Code:**

```
drawer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Apps.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                overridePendingTransition( R.anim.left, R.anim.rtl);
            }
        });
```

**AppsActivity.java:**

```
public class Apps extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences colors_app, color_label;
    GridView mGrid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.apps);

        loadApps();

        mGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.app_grid);

        AppsAdapter adapter = new AppsAdapter(this);
        mGrid.setAdapter(adapter);

        colors_app = getSharedPreferences("MyColor", 1);

        int colorcode2 = colors_app.getInt("color_code", 0);
        if (colorcode2 != 0) {

            Apps.this.findViewById(R.id.apps_back).setBackgroundColor(
                    colorcode2);

        }

        mGrid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View convertView, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ResolveInfo cleckedResolveInfo2 = (ResolveInfo) parent
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                ActivityInfo clickedActivityInfo2 = cleckedResolveInfo2.activityInfo;

                Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"
                        + clickedActivityInfo2.applicationInfo.packageName);
                Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE,
                        packageURI);
                startActivity(uninstallIntent);

                return true;
            }

        });

        mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View convertView,
                    int position, long id) {
                ResolveInfo cleckedResolveInfo = (ResolveInfo) parent
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                ActivityInfo clickedActivityInfo = cleckedResolveInfo.activityInfo;

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                intent.setClassName(
                        clickedActivityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                        clickedActivityInfo.name);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }

    private List<ResolveInfo> mApps;

    private void loadApps() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        mApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

    }

    public class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public AppsAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View grid;

            if (convertView == null) {

                grid = new View(context);
                grid = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_custom, null);

            } else {
                grid = (View) convertView;
            }

            ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);

            ImageView icon = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo
                    .loadIcon(getPackageManager()));

            TextView label = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.label);
            Typeface tf_label = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "fonts/RobotoC-Regular.ttf");
            label.setTypeface(tf_label);
            label.setText(info.activityInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())
                    .toString());

            color_label = getSharedPreferences("LabelColor", 1);

            int color_lab = color_label.getInt("color_code_label", 0);
            if (color_lab != 0) {
                label.setTextColor(color_lab);

            }

            return grid;
        }

        public final int getCount() {
            return mApps.size();
        }

        public final Object getItem(int position) {
            return mApps.get(position);
        }

        public final long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }
}
```

**Nobodys got answer?**

Comment: can you post the stacktrace , when the button is clicked

Comment: Dude, where I'll find that in Eclipse?

Comment: The correct way is the first time load all apps, save it in cache, and the next times load apps in cache and load new apps with an asyntask or UIThread

Comment: Any way to do it? Can you show me an example PLEASE?

Comment: How can I save it in cache?

Answer (score 0):

Profiling the performance of your code will let you see where the bottleneck is.

I would suggest it will be in the `getView()` function:

(1) The function call to `loadLabel` is known to potentially be slow.

[PackageInfo LoadLabel slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659156/packageinfo-loadlabel-slow-performance)

(2) Calling `Typeface.createFromAsset` for every item in the adapter is not a good idea.

Comment: Oh got it, but for launcher customizability, custom typefaces are necessary for me :(

Comment: That's fine, but you can just load it once and keep a reference to the typeface rather than loading it every time getView is called

Comment: Is there any alternative function that can replace `loadLabel`?

Comment: I don't know is there is an alternative to LoadLabel, probably not, you may need look at different solutions, like keeping a persistent cache of the labels. Might be worthwhile taking a look at other peoples launcher implementations to see how they handle the load and if they have performance issues.

Comment: Ohkay dude thanks for your help and time, I appreciate that. Just last wish, can you show me how to keep reference to the typeface?

Comment: Move your createFromAsset call into the constructor and keep the resultant typeface as a member of the class that you can access in the getView() function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79593/discussion-between-ajinkya-more-and-brentm).